# Behaviour of weightless objects (objects in a state of zero gravity) in a vacuum

Tags: gravity, vacuum, levitation

**SCENARIO 1:** So lets say there is a room with no air in it, meaning the room is a vacuum. Now lets say there is a single metal cube (the metal cube is 5kg) in the room, of course gravity still exists so the metal cube would be on the ground. Now what if somehow, the gravity in the vacuum room got erased. (there is no more gravity in the vacuum room). The metal cube will become weightless and start floating, but I want to know till what height it will float too ? (how high will it float) (lets say the room is in the shape of a big cube)  and will it just float and stay in one place or will it keep floating upwards ?

**SCENARIO 2:** Now same scenario, same questions but the room has air in it, what would happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Forces change an object's velocity. The absence of forces means that the object won't change its velocity. So in the simplest approximation, where we say that no force at all is exerted on the cube, we can say: The cube will just stay where it is. It won't float upwards or anything (what even is upwards if we don't have gravity as a reference?).

But that's oversimplified. We should also consider the fact that before we "erased" gravity, the cube also wasn't changing its velocity (just sitting there on the bottom of our box), even though gravity was acting on it. Why not, if forces change velocity? Well, the cube was sitting on the floor of our box, and the floor of the box exerted a force exactly countering the gravitational force, so there is no *net* force acting on our cube. However, if we now take away just the gravitational force, the floor is still exerting the force that previously countered gravity - just with no gravity to counter that force. This means that for a very short amount of time, the floor pushes the cube away. But only as long as there is still contact between the floor and the cube. In this short amount of time, the cube is given some small velocity. And after losing contact with the floor, the cube will experience no force - neither gravity, not the force exerted by the floor. So it will keep its velocity, meaning that it will keep moving away from the floor until some force acts on it - like the roof of the box once the cube reaches it. From there, the cube will probably begin very slowly bouncing around in the box - just up and down in perfect conditions, or chaotically if we allow for little imperfections in either the box or the cube's surface.

If there is still air in the box, the beginning of our scenario is mostly the same, except that the air now exerts frictional forces on the moving cube, slowing it down. And at some point it will come to rest, once the frictional forces have stopped the cube completely. Wether this happens before or after the cube begins bouncing depends on the size of the box and the cube, as well as on the density of the air.

Comment: You said "the floor is still exerting the force that previously countered gravity" How does your floor "remember"

Comment: It doesn't need to remember. In practice, the weight of the object puts a dent in the floor, and the floor being at least slightly elastic will exert a force to remove that dent (like a spring, but on a smaller scale). And when gravity is removed, that dent is still there, so the force exerted by the floor is also still there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering the question

Comment: @trula What's being described here is an elastic force resulting from slight deformation of the floor material which "springs back" when the weight is removed. Imagine laying on a trampoline and then turning gravity off - the elastic force will send you upward since it is no longer balanced by your weight. Important to note that this is *not* a normal force, which is the usual reaction force you feel from the ground. If the floor and box were perfectly rigid and had no elasticity whatsoever, the box would just remain there when gravity was turned off.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie How is it not a normal force? It is normal to the surface in question. There are no perfectly rigid objects, and the normal forces exerted by (almost) rigid objects are elastic forces.

Comment: Thanks, you are right!

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Hm, I suppose a normal force does indeed refer to just the direction being perpendicular to the surface. I suppose I've conflated that with a reactionary force, which doesn't exist without something to oppose. I do think there's a fine line between a reactionary normal force and bulk elastic forces, though - when I push on a wall, it pushes back, but I wouldn't generally consider there to be any time when I've stopped pushing but the wall's reactionary force is still pushing on *me*.

Answer (score 0):

If gravity is "erased" (or, more realistically, if the room and its contents are in freefall) then there is no force keeping the cube on the floor of the room. On the other hand, the cube will not move away from the floor of the room unless some force moves it.

If we suppose the cube is given some small vertical "push" or impulse then it will start to move towards the ceiling of the room. In a vacuum there is nothing to stop the cube once it is moving, so it will float up to the ceiling of the room, bounce off the ceiling, and start to move back towards the floor.

If the room contains air then this will give rise to a drag force which will slow down the cube. If the cube is light enough then the drag force may bring it to a halt before it reaches the ceiling of the room.

Comment: thanks for answering